# Add a second email address from $_SESSION['email'] and send 2 mails

Tags: php, email, contact-form

EDIT:

```
$recipient = $_SESSION['email'];
```

Doesn't work, but

```
$recipient = "myemail@me.com";
```

Works like a charm.

---

I've got a contact form, but I would like to send a different email to the person using the contact form.

So in total 2 mails need to be sent when they click on order (order confirmation for administration, and an order confirmation to the buyer)

His/hers email address is stored in $_SESSION['email'] but I can't get it to work if I put this in a recipient field...

```
<? 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") { 
    if (!$_POST['currentamount'] && !$_POST['nextamount']) { 
        $error_msg ="- You have to order atleast one ticket.<br>"; 
    } 
    if ($_POST['currentamount'] && !$_POST['date1']) { 
        $error_msg ="- You didn't select a date for the current show<br>"; 
    } 
    if ($_POST['nextamount'] && !$_POST['date2']) { 
        $error_msg ="- You didn't select a date the the next show.<br>"; 
    } 

    if (!empty($error_msg)) { 
        //Een van de velden werd niet goed ingevuld 
        echo "<b>Your message can't be send due to the following reason:</b>    <br><br>"; 
        echo $error_msg; 
        echo "<br>Click on <a href='javascript:history.back(1)'>Go back</a> and provide us with the needed information.<br><br>"; 
    } else {
        $recipient = "tickets@*******.com"; //Het email adres van de persoon die vragen moet ontvangen.
        $subject = "MTP: Ticket Order"; //Subject van de mail.
        $header = "From: noreply@*********";
        $mail_body = "Contact script werd op " . date("d-m-Y") . " om " . date("H:i") . " uur uitgevoerd.\n";
        $mail_body .= "De volgende persoon zou graag kaarten bestellen:\n";
        $mail_body .= "Naam: " . $_POST['name2'] . "\n";
        $mail_body .= "Met als kaartnummer: " . $_POST['card2'] . "\n\n";
        $mail_body .= "For the " . $_POST['currentshow'] . ", ". $_POST['name2'] ." would like ". $_POST['currentamount'] ." tickets on date: " . $_POST['date1'] . ".\n";
        $mail_body .= "For the " . $_POST['nextshow'] . ", ". $_POST['name2'] ." would like ". $_POST['nextamount'] ." tickets on date: " . $_POST['date2'] . ".\n";
        $mail_body .= "This gives us a total of : " . $_POST['total2'] . " EUR\n";
        $mail_body .= "\n\n -- ****** --";
        mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header);
        print "<b>IMPORTANT!</b>";
        print "<br><br>Thank you for your reservation.";
        print "<br><br>We are looking forward to meet you.";
    }              
} else {
?>
```

Comment: have you tried to print the value of $_SESSION to see if the correct value is stored?

Comment: Value is stored indeed, made it appear in an input text field.

Comment: Where is your code that assigns e-mail address to recipient?

Comment: would have expected to see `$recipient = $_SESSION['email'];`

Comment: I tried to enter '$recipient = $_SESSION['email'];' but it didn't work :s

Comment: And I would need a second email to be sent as well, so there should the SESSION be put.

Comment: $recipient = $_SESSION['email']; is the correct assignment you are either assigning it in the wrong place or your variable is being overriden. Hard to tell without seing the code. If you want to send two e-mails you should include two e-mails in recipient variable seperated by comma.

Comment: $recipient = $_SESSION['email'] "tickets@*****.com"; <-- where do you put the comma? I've got a SESSION email and a standard email.

Comment: When I replace the "email@me.com" with    $recipient = $_SESSION['email'];     It stops working... And I'm sure the $_SESSION['email'];  works, as I've put it in a text field and I see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up your recipient variable like so:

```
$user_mail =  $_SESSION['email'];
$recipient = "tickets@*******.com,$user_mail";
```

And then mail it like you did

```
mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header);
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: maybe you can try to store the `$_SESSION['email']` in the variable `$recipient` as a string. So before storing the email in the recipient variable convert it in a string, it could work.

Actually you can use an action page with 2 calls to mailer, one for the email to administrator and one for the email to the customer. You can try a thing like this:

```
<?php
// email_sender and email_desitination
$sender_name = "My Name";
$mail_sender = "no-reply@example.com";
$mail_recipient = "customer@gmail.com";

//  subject and mail body
$mail_subject = "Your subject";
$mail_body = "Your message";

// mail headrs
// section for From and some Cc, Bcc, ReplyTo e X-Mailer
$mail_headers = "From: " .  $sender_name . " <" .  $mail_sender . ">\r\n";
$mail_headers .= "Reply-To: " .  $mail_sender . "\r\n";
$mail_headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

if (mail($mail_recipient, $mail_subject, $mail_body, $mail_headers))
  echo "Message sent " . $mail_sender;
else
  echo "Error.";

// second email

// email_sender and email_desitination
$sender_name = "My Name";
$mail_sender = "no-reply@example.com";
$mail_recipient = "customer@gmail.com";

//  subject and mail body
$mail_subject = "Your subject";
$mail_body = "Your message";

// mail headrs
// section for From and some Cc, Bcc, ReplyTo e X-Mailer
$mail_headers = "From: " .  $sender_name . " <" .  $mail_sender . ">\r\n";
$mail_headers .= "Reply-To: " .  $mail_sender . "\r\n";
$mail_headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

if (mail($mail_recipient, $mail_subject, $mail_body, $mail_headers))
  echo "Message sent " . $mail_sender;
else
  echo "Error.";


?>
```

You can send multiple e-mail from the same action.php page